# XACT_ABORT OFF vs COMMIT in trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2014

I have a trigger on a table that kicks off several other processes. However, I would like to ensure that even if the other processes fail, the insert is successfully committed to the original table.

I've been doing this by issuing an explicit `COMMIT TRAN` in the trigger before calling my other procedure. This seems to have been working fine, except for an unsightly error message:

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Upon doing a bit more research I changed the procedure, adding `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;` at the very top, and removed the explicit commit. This seems to have had the same effect.

Which one of these is preferable? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of with either method?

Comment: Look into service broker to kick off these other processes in another transaction.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm already using service broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other code in the trigger that should be allowed to cancel the INSERT, then try the following:

- Keep the `XACT_ABORT OFF`
- Put the `COMMIT TRAN` back
- Add a `BEGIN TRAN` at the end of the trigger

This should be the same issue as if you have an open transaction, exec a proc, and in that proc do a `ROLLBACK` (or even just a `BEGIN TRAN` and no `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`): it will error saying value of `@@TRANCOUNT` is different between entering and exiting the proc.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any error message. What is the point of `XACT_ABORT` in this situation if I'm already doing a commit?

Comment: @Mansfield Because `XACT_ABORT` controls whether or not _any_ error fails the batch. You have already said that you don't want that. Maybe it is ok to leave as ON, but you should test by putting a `SELECT 1/0;` in the trigger to see the effect.

Comment: Okay, so, just so I understand: `COMMIT TRAN` ensures the data gets committed (obviously), `BEGIN TRAN` prevents an error from being thrown, and `XACT_ABORT` makes the batch succeed despite any errors?

Comment: @Mansfield Well, doing that simple test will be better than my memory, but I still think you need, or should have, a TRY / CATCH in the trigger so you can handle errors appropriately.

Comment: I've done the test, and it worked - I just want to make sure I understand what I'm doing. I already had the try/catch in there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mansfield I thought I had seen not long ago a really good write up of XACT_ABORT along with TRY/CATCH and other stuff XACT_STATE and SAVE TRAN but now I can't find it. I thought it written by Aaron Bertrand but the Googles ain't havin it.

Comment: @Mansfield I found the article and it was actually by Phil Factor: [Handling Constraint Violations and Errors in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/handling-constraint-violations-and-errors-in-sql-server/). And thanks Paul, that is another good resource.